# I Can't remove AWS-CDK from Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, npm, aws-cdk

I have installed AWS-CDK on my system. It has been some time since the install, and I can't quite recall the mechanism used to install it, but I cannot seem to remove it now;

```
~:> which cdk
/usr/local/bin/cdk
```

trying to uninstall ...

```
~:> npm uninstall aws-cdk

up to date, audited 1 package in 158ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
~:> npm uninstall -g aws-cdk

removed 1 package, and audited 1 package in 201ms

found 0 vulnerabilities
~:> which cdk
/usr/local/bin/cdk
```

It just doesn't seem to go away?

Is there, perhaps, a different way that I might have installed it other than npm?

I'm running Ubuntu

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Thanks, @gshpychka. I address that in the opening paragraph. I don't actually know how I installed it. I can only find a singular way to do it on the web (via npm), that that isn't consistent with its location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to uninstall it with sudo command.

```
sudo npm uninstall aws-cdk
```

Because `aws-cdk` installs a binary named `cdk` so that we can use it in terminal, you had to install it as root user.

```
sudo npm install aws-cdk
```

So you have to uninstall it as root user.